# Extract the output path from step function trasnform job in python script

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker, aws-step-functions

I have a step function which has a infrence/tranform job and it needs to do thigs calculate prediction result and prediction probablity .

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine for model onboarding",
  "StartAt": "Transform",
  "States": {
    "Transform": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "Transform Job",
          "States": {
            "Transform Job": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sagemaker:createTransformJob.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "TransformJobName.$": "States.Format('test-transform-{}', $$.Execution.Input.currentTimestamp)",
                "ModelName": "model-name",
                "TransformInput": {
                  "DataSource": {
                    "S3DataSource": {
                      "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
                      "S3Uri": "s3://test/input.pq"
                    }
                  },
                  "ContentType": "application/x-npy",
                  "SplitType": "None",
                  "CompressionType": "None"
                },
                "TransformOutput": {
                  "S3OutputPath": "s3://test/output"
                },
                "TransformResources": {
                  "InstanceType": "ml.m5.4xlarge",
                  "InstanceCount": 1
                },
                "BatchStrategy": "SingleRecord",
                "MaxConcurrentTransforms": 1,
                "MaxPayloadInMB": 90
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    },
    "Prem Prediction": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "Prem Prediction Job",
          "States": {
            "Prem Prediction Job": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::sagemaker:createProcessingJob.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "ProcessingJobName.$": "States.Format('test-post-prediction-{}', $$.Execution.Input.currentTimestamp)",
                "ProcessingInputs": [
                  {
                    "InputName": "code",
                    "S3Input": {
                      "S3Uri.$": "States.Format('s3://{}/code/', $$.Execution.Input.s3Bucket)",
                      "LocalPath": "/opt/ml/processing/input/code/",
                      "S3DataType": "S3Prefix",
                      "S3InputMode": "File",
                      "S3DataDistributionType": "FullyReplicated"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "ProcessingResources": {
                  "ClusterConfig": {
                    "InstanceType": "ml.m5.12xlarge",
                    "InstanceCount": 1,
                    "VolumeSizeInGB": 60
                  }
                },
                "NetworkConfig": {
                  "EnableNetworkIsolation": false,
                  "VpcConfig": {
                    "SecurityGroupIds": [
                      "sg-asdasd"
                    ],
                    "Subnets": [
                      "subnet-asdasd"
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "RoleArn.$": "$$.Execution.Input.roleArn",
                "Environment": {
                  "http_proxy": "http://google.com"
                },
                "AppSpecification": {
                  "ImageUri.$": "$$.Execution.Input.imageUri",
                  "ContainerArguments": [
                    "--s3bucket",
                    "test"
                  ],
                  "ContainerEntrypoint": [
                    "python3",
                    "/opt/ml/processing/input/code/premPrediction.py"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

the python code running in tranform job is this

```
def generate_predictions(data:pd.DataFrame, data_format:str):
    """
    Return in data format that was recieved: csv, parquet, gzip, json
    """
    print('predicting')
    predictions = ScoringService.predict(data)
    print(type(predictions))
    predictions_prob = ScoringService.predict_proba(data)
    print(type(predictions_prob))
    print(predictions_prob.shape)
    print('predictions generated')
    if data_format == "text/csv":
        out = io.StringIO()
        predictions.to_csv(out, index=False)
    elif data_format in ["application/parquet","application/gzip"]:
        out = io.BytesIO()
        print('about to save {}'.format(out))
        predictions=pd.DataFrame(predictions)
    elif data_format =="application/x-npy":
        s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
        ## save prediction
        out = io.BytesIO()
        np.save(out, predictions)
        upload_obj = io.BytesIO(out.getvalue())
        bucket_name = "test"
        s3_path = f'output/y_pred_{today}.npy'
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(upload_obj, bucket_name, s3_path)
        ## save prediction probability
        out_pred_prob = io.BytesIO()
        np.save(out_pred_prob, predictions_prob)
        upload_obj_pred_prob = io.BytesIO(out_pred_prob.getvalue())
        bucket_name = "test"
        s3_path = f'output/y_pred_prob_{today}.npy'
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(upload_obj_pred_prob, bucket_name, s3_path)
    elif data_format == "application/json":
        out = io.StringIO()
        predictions.to_json(out, index=False)
    else:
        logging.error(f"Unsupported data_format: {data_format}")
        out = None
        data_format = None

    return out, data_format
```

In this the condition data_format =="application/x-npy": , is there a way i can retrieve the s3output path here rather than harcoding the s3bucket . so that i dont have use hardcoding and get he tranform out value in the python code and then split it to get the sc3 bucket name.

Answer (score 1):

To confirm the generate_predictions function is run in your Batch Transform Job and not the Processing Job mentioned in the Step Function?

If so, why are you uploading the data to S3 in the script? SageMaker Batch Transform will do this for you.

You specify the S3 location in [S3OutputPath](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_TransformOutput.html#sagemaker-Type-TransformOutput-S3OutputPath). I see you specified the below. You should specify a bucket you own in your account and Batch Transform will automatically upload the output to S3 on your behalf.

```
     "TransformOutput": {
                  "S3OutputPath": "s3://test/output"
                },
```

Comment: Yes thats one way . the problem statement i have is i need a specific file name and have two outputs in tranform job python script i.e  predictions = ScoringService.predict(data)
  predictions_prob = ScoringService.predict_proba(data)

Comment: update , i was able to achive it using env variables set  to sagemaker job  in step function .